# H5PY install: error command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: installation, pip

I get the following error:
`command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1` 
when I try to install h5py:
`sudo pip install h5py`
I tried installing python-dev tools. Doesn't work though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running this first solved it for me:
`sudo apt-get install python-h5py`